# bash script: commands after the loop are not executed if the loop condition is false

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, break

I have a strange behavior in my script bash. when the while condition is true the script behaves correctly but if it's false the commands after the loop aren't executed at all and the script stops. There is no break in my commands after the loop. 
I cannot see where is the problem! Any help is welcome :)
Thanks in advance.

```
while  [ expression1 ] || [ expression2 ]  
do
            echo in the loop
            if  [ expression3 ] && [ expression4 ] ;
            then
                    commands..   
                    break;
            fi
            commands..
done
commands..
echo out from the loop
```

Real code:

```
start_t=`grep Start_t $job_template | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
current_date=`date +%s`
progress_t=`expr $current_date - $start_t`
exec_t=`grep Exec_t $job_template | awk -F= '{print $2}'`

running_state="r"
req_state $job_id # get the state 
xml_state=` grep "job_id=$job_id" $list_job_file | awk '{print $4}'`
while  [ $state = $running_state ] || [ $xml_state = "stoped" ]  
    do
            echo in the loop
            if  [ "$xml_state" = "running" ] && [ $progress_t  -gt $exec_t ] ;
            then
                    kill_job $job_id
                    update_status $job_template "killed"
                    echo The job is killed    
                    break;
            fi

            sleep $sleeping_t

            $req_state  $job_id # to update the state
            echo state $state
            xml_state=` grep "job_id=$job_id" $list_job_file | awk '{print $4}' `
            echo xml_state $xml_state
            start_t=`grep Start_t $job_template | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
            current_date=`date +%s`
            progress_t=`expr $current_date - $start_t`
    done
echo out from the loop
commands..
```

Comment: If you do `echo "hi"` immediately after the `done` gets printed?

Comment: You should show us your real script, not a pseudocode. There may be something important missing here.

Comment: check you script once more. script, which repeats your pseudocode definitely works as expected http://paste.ubuntu.com/1270794/

Comment: @ KingsIndian: no it isn't printed.

Comment: @  piokuc: I've added my real script (hope that is not so confusing)

Comment: How about surrounding this with echoes? sleep $sleeping_t ; what is the vaue? Echo it as well. Chances are, it just sleeps there.

Comment: I suspect that bash encounters an error and terminates, probably with an error message.  Run your script like this `bash -x <scriptname>` to trace it.  I suspect that `xml_state` in the loop is eventually being set to an empty string or only spaces, and so the `[ $xml_state = "stoped" ]` expression becomes invalid.  Better to put quotes around `$xml_state`.

Comment: @ full.stack.ex: $sleeping_t contains an integer. The problem isn't here because when the while condition is true the script behaves as expected. And if the condition is false the script will not sleep at all.

Comment: @Austin Phillips: it's the state which was set to an empty string and causes an error. the bash -x <scriptname> was very useful thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes in this script :

- state is not initialised
- as test are done with single right bracket, the variables should be double quoted to avoid shell expansion
- seems req_state is a function or a command, so there must not be preceded by a `$`
- useless use of grep with awk : `grep Start_t $job_template | awk -F= '{print $2}'` and `awk -F= '/Start_t/{print $2}' $job_template` will do the same thing.

Comment: *"there must be a semicolon ; before in-line comments "* -- really?